# SQL Server Merge Replication - Is "Upload Only" Possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, replication

I'm using a merge replication and there doesn't seems to have any "upload only" parameters. I can set a "download only" (from the publisher to the subscribers) but not the other way around. Is it possible? 
(it's for a contact form on the client part).
I use SQL Server 2008

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the filter option on the tables and added a condition like "WHERE 1=0" so no row will ever get "downloaded".

Comment: But watch out, the local table will be empty after the synchronization. It's fine for what I do but it could cause problems in other situations.